# Usar funcion includes javaScript o jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen dia a todos, tengo la siguiente cadena:

```
var str = "ejemplo, hola, prueba, fin, inicio";
```

Y deseo saber si en esa cadena existe alguna palabra como por ejemplo hola, y lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
if (str.includes("hola")){console.log("existe");}
```

En chrome si me funciona muy bien, pero en explorer no, pueden guiarme sobre como puedo solucionar esto, ya se con javaScript o Jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien dices el IE no funciona por que no esta soportado.

[Revisa acá que browser lo soporta y cuales no.](https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-string-includes)

[Aca tambien puedes ver el soporte de esta funcion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Ahora bien podrias incluir el texto de esta forma

```js
var string = "ejemplo, hola, prueba, fin, inicio",
    substring = "hola";


if(string.indexOf(substring) !== -1){
  console.log('la palabra si esta contenida')
} else {
  console.log('la palabra no esta contenida')
}
```